# the type or namespace common could not be found

Tags: c#, namespaces, itext

I have error  "the type or namespace common could not be found"

im using iTextSharp 5.4.4

What is the problem here?

Please help im looking for this solution for days...

```
using (FileStream msReport = new FileStream("Ima se moze se", FileMode.Create))
        {
            //step 1
            using (Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 140f, 10f))
            {
                try
                {
                    // step 2
                    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, msReport);
                    pdfWriter.PageEvent = new Common.ITextEvents();

                    //open the stream 
                    pdfDoc.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Hello world. Checking Header Footer");
                        para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                        pdfDoc.Add(para);
                        pdfDoc.NewPage();
                    }

                    pdfDoc.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //handle exception
                }
                finally
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Remove "Common.", click on `ITextEvents` and then press `Ctrl`+`.` on the keyboard - it should prompt you to import the using. Does this happen?